# Blocking clients by IP using dynamic list in NGINX

Tags: nginx, security, fail2ban, blacklist

I have a service using nginx as a frontend server. Some bots constantly bruteforcing /login page and it is sufficiently drops my server productivity.

What I want to do is to count amount of login fails (in PHP) and then update an IP blacklist and then using this list to ban clients by IP to access only /login page. (This is to avoid occassional bans of "good" crawlers, which will be able to read other pages of site even being "banned" on login page).

How to implement nginx ban from dynamic list of IP?

Comment: What you are seeing is the drawback of using a slow hashing algorithm. But simply blocking IP addresses is not a viable strategy either because of the widespread usage of CGN, which means you'd end up locking out legitimate users.

Comment: @kasperd I will only blocks IPs which made more than 20 failed tries. There is no users who can do that manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is basically Fail2ban.

https://www.fail2ban.org/

In your PHP script, you could log the login tentatives, and then parse&act on that with Fail2ban.

Comment: +1 for fail2ban. You can create your own logs with your application, but can also simply use it to look at nginx logs for HTTP 403.

Comment: fail2ban won't work because there is no way to dynamically block at nginx level (and not firewall level) in nginx community edition. In some cases blocking on firewall is ok but not when you are behind something like cloudflare. firewall would block entire cloudflare.